# Swift: When changing ViewControllers: the previous one doesn't dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, uikit

I'm a noobie when it comes to UIKit and ViewControllers. I'm trying to switch from `SplashScreenViewController` to `GameViewController` which is a SKView. GameViewController is loaded ok as I can hear the game music starting, but the `SplashScreenController` never dismisses from the screen. So basically I have `SplashScreenController` staying on screen and I can hear the `GameViewController` starting in the background. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code for the `SplashScreenViewController`:

```
class SplashScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:  46/255, green: 83/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1.0)
        let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"splashScreen.png")!
        let bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)

        bgImage.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 3,y: -3), size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
        self.view.addSubview(bgImage)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameViewController")
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        print("Object with name SplashScreenViewController is being released")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's simple please present nextviewcontroller on the completion of dismissViewController method.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I guess it only works, if there is one view controller left, after `SplashScreenViewController` has been dismissed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [rootviewcontroller](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwindow/1621581-rootviewcontroller) of your window to replace splash screen with game screen.
The code will look like this

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = gameViewController
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you want to replace the `SplashScreenViewController` with your `GameViewController`. Your current code is presenting the `GameViewController`modally and directly after that dismissing it. So the new view controller isn't shown.

Another problem in your code is the missing gap in timing, currently the splash screen get's initialized and right after that it would be replaced by the `GameViewController`if your code was working, so you would just see the `GameViewController`.

```
class SplashScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:  46/255, green: 83/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1.0)
        let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"splashScreen.png")!
        let bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)

        bgImage.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 3,y: -3), size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
        self.view.addSubview(bgImage)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameViewController")            

        // Here we create a dispatch queue to do some other code after an amount of time. In this case, one second.
        let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime) {
           self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([controller!], animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

This setup will replace the SplashScreenViewController with the GameViewController after one second. For that to work, and for basically all navigation between view controllers, you must wrap your first view controller into a `UINavigationController`.